# VB6 to VS2015 Upgrade > Loop Error

Tags: .net, visual-studio, vb6

I recently was hired to fix some code for a company, but being new to coding, I'm having an issue figuring out how to fix the error given when they upgraded from Visual Basic 6.0 to Visual Studio 2015. Here is the error:

'GoTo UP_NUM' is not valid because 'UP_NUM' is inside a 'With' statement that does not contain this statement.

Here is a snippet of the function/code I'm working with:

```
    Function UpdateItemFileNum() As Boolean
   Dim iNumErrorsThrown, iNumErrorsAllowed As Short
   Dim lErrorNum As Integer
   Dim sProcedureName, lFunctionName, lErrorDes, currTask As String 'Intra-Procedure tag
   '***Stop Error handler Variables*****
   Dim returnValue As Boolean
   'UPGRADE_WARNING: Arrays in structure baseRS may need to be initialized before they can be used. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="814DF224-76BD-4BB4-BFFB-EA359CB9FC48"'
   Dim baseRS As dao.Recordset
   Dim db As dao.Database
   Dim lvCMax As Integer

   lFunctionName = cvconClassName & ":.UpdateItemFileNum!"
   currTask = "Start Function" 'establish default position
   returnValue = True 'establish default position
   On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLER


   db = DAODBEngine_definst.OpenDatabase(gpConversionDb.Name, , False)

   '<obtain the max
   baseRS = db.OpenRecordset("Select MAX(VAL(NUM)) FROM ItemFile")
   lvCMax = 50000
   lvCMax = baseRS.Fields(0).Value
   Call gpConversionDb.Execute("Update ItemFile Set Num = val(num) + " & lvCMax)
   MAX_ITEM_NUM = 1
   '   >

   baseRS = db.OpenRecordset("ItemFile", dao.RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenTable)
   With baseRS
       Do While Not.EOF
           MAX_ITEM_NUM = MAX_ITEM_NUM + 1
           .Edit()
    UP_NUM:
           .Fields("NUM").Value = MAX_ITEM_NUM
           .Update()
           .MoveNext() 'cycle next record
       Loop
   End With 'baseRS

    PROC_EXIT:  'Close Resources

   If Not baseRS Is Nothing Then
       baseRS.Close()
       'UPGRADE_NOTE: Object baseRS may not be destroyed until it is garbage collected. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6E35BFF6-CD74-4B09-9689-3E1A43DF8969"'
       baseRS = Nothing
   End If

   UpdateItemFileNum = returnValue
   Exit Function 'Exit here

    ERR_HANDLER:
   returnValue = False
   With Err
       lErrorNum = Err.Number
       lErrorDes = Err.Description
       sProcedureName = .Source
   End With
   iNumErrorsThrown = iNumErrorsThrown + 1 'talley errors
   If lErrorNum = 3022 Then
       MAX_ITEM_NUM = MAX_ITEM_NUM + 1
       currTask = "Try up num"
       gjLog__LogEntry(jLogEnumEvents.errror, lFunctionName & sProcedureName & " ERROR#:" & lErrorNum, lErrorDes, , "<", "Task", currTask, "@@")
       Resume UP_NUM
   End If
   If iNumErrorsThrown<iNumErrorsAllowed Then 'When exceeded exit to avoid infinite loops
       gjLog__LogEntry(jLogEnumEvents.errror, lFunctionName & sProcedureName & " ERROR#:" & lErrorNum, lErrorDes, , "<", "Task", currTask, "@@")
       Resume Next
   Else
       'ask errordecision?
       gjLog__LogEntry(jLogEnumEvents.errror, lFunctionName & sProcedureName & " ERROR#:=" & lErrorNum, "REACHED_MAX_ERRORS:=" & lErrorDes, , "<", iNumErrorsThrown & " Thrown", iNumErrorsAllowed & " Max", "Task:=", currTask, "@@")
       Resume PROC_EXIT
   End If
       End Function
```

Any/all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is no `GoTo Up_NUM` in your code. But in any case, [`With`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) is just a syntactic sugar to access properties of a single object in sequence. Have you tried expanding the `With` statement?

Comment: The error is referencing the "Resume UP_NUM" portion of the above code. I haven't attempted to expand the With statement yet.

Comment: A lot of questions .... why get the max(val(num)) and then update EVERY record? Is the remaing part a simple "renumbering" of Items? This is - sorry to say - the most awful code I´v ever seen. Depending on your database it´s maybe a task for a single update statement. Try to find out what the result of the snipplet should be, and REWRITE it from scratch.